# Remove all files added by revision X

Tags: svn

Let's say the Head revision is 10 in our SVN branch.
Revision 7 consisted of 100 new files which were added to various locations in the branch.
Now I want to remove all the files which rev 7 brought in.
How do I do that?

Comment: Was Rev 7 only adds, or were there modifications, etc. too?

Comment: only adds. but it would be cool to know how if there were mods as well

Comment: Why not just update to r10, delete the files and commit to r11 ? or do want to have them removed from the history too ?

Comment: because there are 100 of them and they are scattered across the paths

Comment: This is easy with TortoiseSVN (view log, revert changes from this revision). Not sure how to do it with command line tools.

Comment: @crashmstr, addendum: remember to Windows delete the now-non-versioned files. Easy to accomplish with TortoiseSVN's `Cleanup` command

Comment: If your only concern is finding the paths you could use `svn log -v -r 7  %REPO%` to list all changes done by revision `7`, Files added will have the prefix `A`. save that output to a text file and edit it (make a script of it) to remove the files/directories added. There has to be no dependencies of them otherwise your source will be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common scenario, so common that it's [explained in the Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo)

Basically, you're going to perform a merge which reverses the change made in revision 7. `svn merge -r7:6 <URL>`. Review the results, then commit.

Comment: Even easier: `svn merge -c -7`. It says to remove changes in revision 7. (negative number means remove). It's the same as the command you gave, but it's just easier to remember.

Comment: Yep, that's available as well. I always forget the syntax for it (the negative part), and specifying the revisions like I did is easier for me to remember and clearer for me to understand. Whichever floats your boat.